# Reversing Time Set Command

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am playing version 1.10 and on a creative/survival map with commands enabled. I put in the time command, `/time set <TIME-OF-DAY>`, so it was always daytime while I was building my town/city. Is there any way to reverse this? When I go back into survival mode it still remains the same time and I haven't been able to figure out how to change it back to normal. Thank you!

Comment: Did you put that in a repeating command block, or did you change any `/gamerule`s?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the command running on a repeating command block you would need to stop or break the command block and the time will continue as normal.

You can also use the gamerule  doDaylightCycle command if it has been set to false (which stops time (day/night) from passing.

```
 /gamerule doDaylightCycle true
```

Comment: Thank you! The /gamerule doDaylightCycle true commands worked!

Answer (score 0):

You can also switch to always day go in your world then exit your world then switch always day off and it will do just the trick!